# SQL Query with double distinct dates iteration, and start date < my date < final date

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I have a kind of rental system database where user can rent an entire house, or just a room of the house.

I have a table called `offers` which has columns `id`, `room_id` and a few more.

If `room_id = NULL`, it refers to an entire house.

I have a table called `availability` which has columns `offer_id`, `room_id`, `date`, `status` (available, unavailable)

If `room_id = NULL`, it refers to an availability of an entire house.

```
select `offer_id` , `room_id`
from `availability` 
where `date` > CAST('2016-05-17' as date) 
  and `date` <= CAST('2016-05-21' as date) 
  and `status` = 'available' 
group by `offer_id` 
having COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) = DATEDIFF('2016-05-21', '2016-05-17')
```

Ok, but my problem is: if a room is unavailable at day 20 but the house have another room available at day 20 the query will return a false and indistinct select. I need all those availability where room_id is null(an entire house), and a separated result where room_id is not null and distinct when compare the dates for each offer_id (offer_id= 1 and room_id = 1, offer_id = 1 and room_id = 2 ...)

SAMPLE DATA:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5dfe

```
CREATE TABLE `availability` (
`offer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`room_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`status` enum('available','UNAVAILABLE') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'available'
);

INSERT INTO `availability` (`offer_id`, `room_id`, `date`, `status`) VALUES
(1, NULL, '2016-05-18', 'UNAVAILABLE'),
(1, NULL, '2016-05-19', 'available'),
(1, NULL, '2016-05-20', 'available'),
(1, NULL, '2016-05-21', 'available'),
(1, 1, '2016-05-18', 'available'),
(1, 1, '2016-05-19', 'UNAVAILABLE'),
(1, 1, '2016-05-20', 'available'),
(1, 1, '2016-05-21', 'available'),
(1, 2, '2016-05-18', 'available'),
(1, 2, '2016-05-19', 'UNAVAILABLE'),
(1, 2, '2016-05-20', 'available'),
(1, 2, '2016-05-21', 'available'),
(1, 3, '2016-05-18', 'available'),
(1, 3, '2016-05-19', 'available'),
(1, 3, '2016-05-20', 'UNAVAILABLE'),
(1, 3, '2016-05-21', 'available');
```

using the query above will give me one result (offer_id = 1), but the correct is no results.
because none entire house (room_id = null) or a room is available when search the dates where all dates appear available between start date and final date

Comment: What do you mean with " I need all those availability where room_id is null(an entire house), and a separated where room_id is not null and distinct when compare the dates"?

Comment: If you provided sample data and desired results, the question would be much clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have provided some sample data

Comment: @aquiros I have provided some sample and improved the phrase

Comment: But there is one available. You are asking for a record where date is between 18 and 21 and status is avalable. The second record "1, NULL, '2016-05-19', 'available'" has that description (19 is between 18 and 21 and is available)

Comment: @aquiros all the rows need to have a date between 18 and 21 (18,19,20,21 all those days included), and all these rows need to be available, and all these rows need to be distinct with room_id when compare

Comment: another question: if I'm looking for an entire house, from 18 to 21 and there's a record on 19 but room_id not null should it return false or true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as initial answer was incorrect:
The following fiddle has more data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6602/1/0

```
SELECT `Offer_id`, `room_id`
from
    ( select `offer_id`, `room_id`
    from `availability` 
    where `date` > CAST('2016-05-17' as date) 
      and `date` <= CAST('2016-05-21' as date) 
      and `status` = 'available'
    group by `offer_id`, `room_id`
    having COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) = DATEDIFF('2016-05-21', '2016-05-17')) As HousesAndRooms
WHERE NOT `room_id` IS NULL OR (`room_id` is null AND`offer_id` NOT IN(
    ( select `offer_id`
    from `availability` 
    where `date` > CAST('2016-05-17' as date) 
      and `date` <= CAST('2016-05-21' as date) 
      and `status` = 'UNAVAILABLE'
      and not `room_id` is null
    group by `offer_id`, `room_id`
    having COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) > 0 ) 
  ) )
```

The query above selects all available offers (houses and rooms) for a date range, where room_id is null (i.e. a whole house) it will check if there are any unavailable rooms (not room_id is null) for a given date range.

Comment: You almost got it!, I am posting full answer, thanks to your help!

Comment: I can't comment in your answer (no reputation). If I understood correctly it should not return [2, null] as whole house is not available, room 2 is booked on 2016-05-18. Please check my revised answer.